# Max value of a homogeneous function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given a homogeneous function of degree 1 $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$
$$f(tx,ty)=tf(x,y)$$
I must prove that, if $f$ is positive and it has a maximum value in $(x_{0},y_{0})$ then $f(x_{0},y_{0})=0$.

Since $(x_{0},y_{0})$ is a max point of $f$, then it's a critical point of it. Derivating the left side of the expression above:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(tf(x,y))=t\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$$
So, for $(x,y)=(x_{0},y_{0})$:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(tf(x_{0},y_{0}))=t\cdot\underbrace{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_{0},y_{0})}_{=0}=0$$

And, certainly
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(tf(x_{0},y_{0}))=0$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(tx_{0},ty_{0}))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(tf(x_{0},y_{0}))=0$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f(tx_{0},ty_{0}))=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(tf(x_{0},y_{0}))=0$$
Now I don't know what I'm suppose to do to conclude that
$$f(x_{0},y_{0})=0$$

Comment: Hint: What is the value of $f(t x_0, t y_0)$ for $t>1$?

Comment: @MathLover $tf(x_{0},y_{0})$ and I still don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ has a maximum at $(x_0,y_0)$, then $tf(x_0,y_0)=f(tx_0,ty_0)\leq f(x_0,y_0)$ for all $t\geq 0$. Since $f$ is non-negative, this forces $f(x_0,y_0)$ to be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that we have  $$0 \le f(x,y) \le f(x_0,y_0).$$

For $(x,y)=(tx_0,ty_0)$, where $t>1$, we have $$f(x,y)=f(tx_0,ty_0) = t f(x_0,y_0) \le f(x_0,y_0) \implies (t-1)f(x_0,y_0) \le 0 \implies f(x_0,y_0) \le 0.$$
But $f(x_0,y_0) \ge 0$. Therefore, $f(x_0,y_0)=0$.